# Hibernate on update a column not refreshed while retrieving the row

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have a service layer in that in I have to fetch the sample data by id and perform some validation check, if all ok then i am updating the status of it.
Once updating the status I fetch the same row from DB and create a file.

In this after update due to hibernate first level cache the status what i am updating is not refreshed when in createFile() method.

I have seen a workaround is to update the status manually. But is there any better way to do instead of updating the status? Thanks in advance.

Service Layer

```
@Override
 update(String id){
    Sample sample= sampleDao.findById(id);
    // perform validation if all ok proceed

    sampleDao.updateStatus(id, status);
    createFile(id);
}

boolean createFile(String id) {
    Sample sample=  sampleDao.findById(id);
    // Do create file as based on 
}
```

sampleDao Layer

```
@Override
public Sample findById(String id) {
    return sampleRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public boolean updateStatus(String id,Integer status) {
    return this.sampleRepository.updateStatus(status, id) ;
}
```

sampleRepository

```
@Modifying()
    @Query("update Sample sample set sample.status.id = :status where sample.id = :id")
    Integer updateStatus(@Param("status") Integer status, @Param("id") String id);
```

sample Entity

```
class Sample {
    String id;  
    Status status;
 }

  class Status {
    String id;  
    String name;
 }
```

Comment: why you retrieve same data again? You can just update status, create file and save data

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer may help, I solved this issue by using **clearAutomatically** attribute

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
```

So, with this when I make a call findById(), 2nd time call actually goes to DB and fetches.

Hope this is helpful.